# How to filter xts objects on columns other than the index

Tags: r

Running the code below shows that on 2011-08-28, the column "BTC-EUR.Volume" has the value 0. Shouldn't `BTC-EUR`["BTC-EUR.Volume" == 0,] list all rows that have the value 0 on column "BTC-EUR.Volume"?

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols(Symbols = "BTC-EUR", src = "yahoo", from = "1900-01-01", to = Sys.Date())
head(`BTC-EUR`)
`BTC-EUR`["BTC-EUR.Volume" == 0,]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the column name,

```
colnames(`BTC-EUR`)
#[1] "BTC-EUR.Open"     "BTC-EUR.High"     "BTC-EUR.Low"      "BTC-EUR.Close"    "BTC-EUR.Volume"   "BTC-EUR.Adjusted"
```

we need to extract the column name and subset

```
`BTC-EUR`[`BTC-EUR`[,"BTC-EUR.Volume"] == 0,]
#       BTC-EUR.Open BTC-EUR.High BTC-EUR.Low BTC-EUR.Close BTC-EUR.Volume BTC-EUR.Adjusted
#2011-08-28         6.40         6.40        6.40          6.40              0             6.40
#2011-08-29         6.40         6.40        6.40          6.40              0             6.40
#2011-08-30         6.40         6.40        6.40          6.40              0             6.40
#2011-08-31         6.40         6.40        6.40          6.40              0             6.40
#2011-09-03         5.83         5.83        5.83          5.83              0             5.83
```

Or use `subset`

```
subset(`BTC-EUR`, `BTC-EUR.Volume` == 0)
```